# Define a function as the partial derivative of another

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I just want to write something like

```
f[x_] := x[[1]]^2 + x[[2]]^3
g[x_] := D[f[y], {y}] /. y -> x
```

I know this is probably very wrong in many ways but I am quite new to mathematica. I just want to know how to define the partial derivative of functions.

Comment: You should probably learn about the difference between [immediate assignments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [delayed assignments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html), for example from [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#29979).

Answer (score 4):

Using explicit parameter lists, and [immediate assignments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html):

```
f[{x1_, x2_}] = x1^2 + x2^3;
g[{x1_, x2_}] = D[f[{x1, x2}], {{x1, x2}}]

(*    {2 x1, 3 x2^2}    *)
```

If you don't need parameter lists, you can use the parameters directly (without curly braces):

```
f[x1_, x2_] = x1^2 + x2^3;
g[x1_, x2_] = D[f[x1, x2], {{x1, x2}}]

(*    {2 x1, 3 x2^2}    *)
```

Comment: Although this kind of works, when I try to input a value into g like g[{1,3}], it tries to take the derivative with respect to 1. How do I fix this?

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan please look at a tutorial about the distinction between immediate and delayed assignments. A delayed assignment `:=`, as you use it, will not work; you'll need an immediate assignment `=` as I've used in the above code. My code does not have the problem that you describe.